# Can Query be re initialized multiple times?

Tags: hibernate

This is my code

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
String sqlQuery = "from FacultyAchievements fa where fa.isActive = 1";
Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);
if(facultyAchievementsForm.getFilterAcademicYear() != null && !facultyAchievementsForm.getFilterAcademicYear().isEmpty())
{
    sqlQuery += " and fa.academicYear = :academicYear";
    query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);
    query.setString("academicYear",facultyAchievementsForm.getFilterAcademicYear());
}
if(facultyAchievementsForm.getEmployeeId() != null && !facultyAchievementsForm.getEmployeeId().isEmpty())    
{
    sqlQuery += " and fa.employee.employee.id = :employeeId"; 
    query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);
    query.setInteger("employeeId", Integer.parseInt(facultyAchievementsForm.getEmployeeId()));
}
List<FacultyAchievements> achivementsList = query.list();
session.flush();
if(achivementsList != null)
    return achivementsList;
else
    return new ArrayList<FacultyAchievements>();
```

and the exception I'm getting is -

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set

But I've set all the parameters correctly, so my doubt is that due to the re initialization of `Query` multiple times is causing the problem. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in using plain sql when you are explictly using the Hibernate Session, [Criteria api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) or [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) would be a better choice. If you wanna stay vendor independent you could use [JPA named queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named).

To solve your problem, refactor your code like this:

```
if (a)
   sqlQuery += "a...";
if (b)
   sqlQuery += "b...";
query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);
if (a)
   query.setParam(...
if (b)
   query.setParam(...
```

Comment: **@Journeycorner** I've tried it and was successfull, thank you

Comment: Sorry I forgot 
 
@Journeycorner

Answer (score 0):

The `session.createQuery(sqlQuery);` returns you  new query object. You are setting only one param to a query object in your if block. In the second if block you are not setting the param to the same query object which you created in first if block. Your code has bug.